# Git check for corrupted files in the working directory

Tags: windows, git, corruption, data-corruption

#### Context

I had a Windows crash (I had to cut the power to the PC) during work and a bunch of files got corrupted (random binary data overwritten on text files, things like this). I noticed this because git didn't recognize the folder as a git repo anymore (at least `.git/HEAD` and `.git/index` got corrupted) and some text file inside the working dir got corrupted.

Fortunately everything was pushed to the remote so this isn't about recovering uncommitted changes.

For git itself I recovered it by deleting `.git/`, `git init`, `remote add` and `fetch`.

#### The problem

Because of the crash I felt I couldn't trust `git status` to know if there are modifications to the files (i.e. corrupted files). Maybe Windows corrupted files without git knowing about it. Maybe files got corrupted at a hardware level during the power shutdown (e.g. files being written from cache, ssd reorganizing data internally during the forced power shutdown).

I did `git fsk` and `git lfs fsck` but from the documentation it seems to me this checks that the internal structure of the git repo is valid (i.e. `./.git/**`).

#### The question

Is there a way for git to check every file in the repository comparing it **bit by bit** with the index to detect modifications? I suppose hash comparison would also be ok. Or maybe am I wrong and `git status` already does that (my assumption is that git uses some OS callbacks to get notified when a file is modified).

I ended up deleting everything and cloning it again, but I want to know if there is a better way (as for some repos cloning can take a lot of hours).

---

Using git on Windows (default official install, with lfs files in the repo, from within Windows Terminal, Windows 10)

Comment: The easiest I can think of would be to `git rm -r --cached .` && `git add .` && `git commit -m "changes?"` && `git diff HEAD~`...

Comment: @AKX I could do `git status` after `git add .` without the need to commit right?

Comment: Yeah, that should probably work too. But a commit is basically free (you can always back out with `git reset --hard HEAD~`)

Comment: `git status`/`git diff` already do that. There might be some caches at play, but they will be invalidated anyway if you restart your computer. You might want to look into the options outlined in https://git-scm.com/docs/git-status#_untracked_files_and_performance

Comment: @knittl so `git status` does a read (full file content read) of all files in the working directory, correct?

Comment: @bolov it might skip some files based on modification date, but you should definitely check the linked options. Maybe there's also a way of dropping and recreating the index file